# How should I format a curl for a HTTP request in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, wit.ai

I know there is an library made by an individual (https://github.com/tgallice/wit-php). However, I can't find how he formatted the curl. I only want to do one request, so using his library would be overkill.

Here is the string that works in terminal, but I'm not sure how to write in PHP: `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESSCODE' 'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160526&q=mycarisbroken'`

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160526&q=my%20car%20doesnt%20work");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ACCESSCODEOMITTED',
];

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);
Data::$answer = json_decode($server_output)['entities']['intent'][0]['value'];
```

Comment: check out [libcurl](http://php.net/curl/)

Comment: @HassanAhmed I don't know what the -H is, so that link doesn't help much

Comment: the -H flag in curl represent the header you are sending to server

Comment: @HassanAhmed I still can't get it right, not sure if this is a GET or a POST. Where would the header go in a curl?

Comment: by default curl command request type is GET , as long as you didn't defined it as POST

Comment: @HassanAhmed I updated my question with the code I'm trying, but this is not working

Comment: after executing your function on my machine i got a response `"error" : "Bad auth, check token/params",` which is mean that your code is working but you need to trace the request and provide more headers and cookies detials

Comment: You might use [curl_error($ch1)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) for getting a better error message

Comment: Can anyone help?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line you gave will send a GET to the remote server - but in your code you send a POST. Comment out `curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` and your PHP code will do exactly what the command line does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this PHP library https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class. Basically it wraps all of php curl functions to class. You can easily create mocks of your implementation afterwards and write decent unit tests.

Your code should look something like that:

```
<?php 
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ACCESSCODEOMITTED');
$curl->get('htps://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160526&q=mycarisbroken');

if ($curl->error) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $curl->errorCode . ': ' . $curl->errorMessage . "\n";
} else {
  echo 'Response:' . "\n";
  var_dump($curl->response);
}
```